# macOS Siri shows scheduling event on wrong day

Tags: calendar, ical, siri

This is weird… I've recently upgraded from Mavericks to Sierra, so I've been getting used to having Siri on my computer.  I schedule things all the time with her on my phone, but on the desktop it's new for me.

So I just tried to schedule an all-day event for November 24th.  The notification displayed as expected asking me to confirm it, but it says November 25th in the calendar cell, and November 24th in the header above:

[image]

The resulting event however once accepted, is in fact on November 24th as desired, but still something clearly seems wrong.  Anyone have any ideas why this happens?  Or is there a bug?